# How to block threads on a condition

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method which is invoked by multiple threads.

```
public void notifyCompleted(PlayerDTO winner, PlayerDTO loser) {
    PlayerRankedData winnerData = rankedDataMap.get(winner.getId());
    PlayerRankedData loserData = rankedDataMap.get(loser.getId());

    int pointsToAdd = getPointsToAdd(winnerData, loserData);
    int pointsToDeduct = getPointsToDeduct(loserData, winnerData);

    winnerData.addMatchPoints(pointsToAdd);
    loserData.deductMatchPointsUptoMinimum(pointsToDeduct, minimumMatchPoints);

    winnerData.addRewardTokens(tokenPerVictory);
}
```

And I have another method which is accessed by a scheduler, and runs only once in a month i.e. It resets the monthly ranked data for players.

```
private void resetLadder() {
    for (PlayerRankedData playerRankedData : rankedDataMap.values()) {
        int monthlyTokens = playerRankedData.getRewardTokens() * calculateTierMultiplier(playerRankedData);
        playerRankedData.setUnlockedTokens(monthlyTokens);

        playerRankedData.resetMonthlyDataData();  //This updates reward tokens, matchPoints and other variables which are modified inside notifyCompleted.

        updateOnDatabase(playerRankedData);
    }
}
```

What I want is that when `resetLadder` is running, `notifyCompleted` waits until `resetLadder` finishes its execution.

I can make it work by using a lock object and locking the body of `notifyCompleted` and `resetLadder` but I don't want to do that because then only 1 thread will be able to access `notifyCompleted` at a time which I don't want. Its completely fine for multiple threads to access notifyCompleted.

I think busy waiting with an AtomicBoolean can kind of make it work but issue is that if `notifyCompleted` is running and `resetLadder` starts running then it will lead to inconsistent state.

So my question is, is there a way to make `notifyCompleted` to run but only be blocked when resetLadder is running and resetLadder to not start when `notifyCompleted` is not running.

Comment: Why don't use an AtomicInteger? Negative value : somebody in resetLadder, positive or nul value : number of threads in notifyCompleted...

Comment: You could use a ReadWriteLock i guess

Comment: Well there is no reading but only writing @nithinnambiar and as I mentioned notifyCompleted will be accessed by multiple threads and using lock there will make the other threads wait for no reason. P.S. ReadWriteLock won't solve this :/

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès you mean wrapping AtomicInteger in a syncronized and have busy waits? That can work I think.

Comment: With ReadWriteLock you may have resetLadder as “write” operation and notifyCompleted as “read”

Comment: Busy waits are horrible. In notifyComplete as long as you're not writing shared state it can count as a reader. Go with @nithin's suggestion.

Comment: I agree on busy waits being horrible :) I am writing shared state in notifyComplete i.e. addRewardTokens. RewardTokens are reset to 0 inside resetMonthlyData. I will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @algrid my bad I should have mentioned that resetMonthlyData updates rewardToken to 0 which is also modified inside notifyCompleted.

Comment: @Sneh you just need to do `readWriteLock.readLock().lock();` inside your notifyCompleted method so that multiple threads could access it. do `readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();` in other method which would make other thread wait till resetLadder method is completed.

Comment: @nithinnambiar I think I am very stupid that I didn't think about that.... Having used ReadWriteLock earlier and even understanding it, I somehow today thought that readLock() will read even when write is happening.... Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. I realised I asked a stupid question just because I manage to confuse myself with ReentrantReadWriteLock and ReentrantLock.